# PHP speed issue when reading lots of images EXIF dates

Tags: php, performance, exif

I want to list and order by date the pictures in a directory (to then compare with a database and display those which are not in the DB).

I have some thousands of them, and it already takes a few seconds to read the filetime() date, but if I want to use EXIF dates, it's even slower.

Here are the functions I'm using now, do you think I could speed up the process ?

1. Read the files in a directory and try to extract EXIF date from the file, else read filetime() :

```
`function list_images ($path)
{
        $images = array();
        foreach (scandir($path) as $node)
        {
                $nodePath = $path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $node;
                if (is_dir($nodePath) OR !preg_match("£.jpg|.png|.bmp|.gif£", $node)) continue;
                if (preg_match('£.jpg£i', $node) AND exif($nodePath, array('date'))['date'] != '')
                {
                        $images[$node] = strtotime(exif($nodePath, array('date'))['date']);
                }
                else
                {
                        $images[$node] = filemtime($nodePath);
                }

        }
        arsort($images);
        return $images;
}`
```

2. generic (larger) exif function :

```
  `function exif($imagePath, $exif = '')
    {
            if ($exif === '') $exif[] = 'All';
            if ((isset($imagePath)) and (file_exists($imagePath)))
            {
    // There are 2 arrays which contains the information we are after, so it's easier to state them both
                    $exif_ifd0 = @read_exif_data($imagePath ,'IFD0' ,0);
                    $exif_exif = @read_exif_data($imagePath ,'EXIF' ,0);
    // ... (other exif groups)
                    $notFound = "";
                    $return = array();
    // ... (other exif data)
    // Date
                    if (in_array('date', $exif) OR in_array('All', $exif))
                    {
                            if (@array_key_exists('DateTimeOriginal', $exif_exif))
                            {
                                    $camDate = $exif_exif['DateTimeOriginal']; 
                            }
                            elseif (@array_key_exists('DateTime', $exif_ifd0))
                            {
                                    $camDate = $exif_ifd0['DateTime'];
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                    $camDate = $notFound;
                            }
                            $return['date'] = $camDate;
                    }
    }`
```

The issue (and question !) is about EXIF reading performance, but maybe another process could be used, instead of retrieving all images dates in an array, substract the database result from this array, then display the (20 or so) most recent ?

Comment: Have you consider using [imagemagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) instead?

Comment: No. After a quick glance at imagemagick class, I can't find any method in relation to date or exifs. I will try to look better later.